# always login successfully in the get method

Tags: swift, swift3, authentication, alamofire

I have an authentication login code, but my coding always makes me login successfully, even though the username and password I used was incorrect. where is my coding error?

this my code

```
    let username = self.txtUsername.text
    let password = self.txtPassword.text
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username!, password!)
    let loginData: Data = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString(options: [])

    let parameters = [
        "username": txtUsername.text!,
        "password": txtPassword.text!
    ]

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .get, parameters:parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                let Main1VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Main1VC, animated: true)
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                print("success for login")
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            //print(response.result.error)
            print("failed to login")
            break

        }
    }
```

and this response I received from the url if it's wrong

```
{
  "success": false,
  "msg": "Email / ID Finger Tidak Terdaftar"
}
```

and this response I received from the url if it's correct

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Sukses"
}
```

Comment: 1) you are not comparing "success" key value

Comment: Something seems odd. You will have to fetch the value for key "success" in the responding JSON and the put that value into your switch case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  let data = response.result.value
  self.presentWindow.hideToastActivity()
  if let response = data as? [String: AnyObject] { 
       let success = response["success"] as? Bool
       if success {
          let Main1VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Main1VC, animated: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            print("success for login")
       } else{
            print("Failed for login")
        }
   }
```

Comment: I tried and now it's always wrong when I have entered the correct username and password

Comment: try to check what success variable get

Comment: like above, this response I received from the url if it's correct

{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Sukses"
}

Comment: let success = response["success"] as? Bool
print(success)

Comment: try this nd let me know what u get?

Comment: i get Optional(false)

Comment: thats why u r going in else part because response getting false

Comment: how can be like that? even though I entered the username and password correctly. Is the coding parameter wrong?

Comment: @Firuma try to debug check your parameter properly some spce anything mismatch that it will return false

Comment: your answer is correct, but in my application I still look wrong, can you help me finish this?